# Hive: insert into table by Hue produces different number of files than pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, cloudera, hue

I have a Cloudera cluster on which I am accumulating large amounts of data in a Hive table stored as Parquet. The table is partitioned by an integer `batch_id`. My workflow for inserting a new batch of rows is to first insert the rows into a staging table, then insert into the large accumulating table. I am using a local-mode Python Pyspark script to do this. The script is essentially:

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
hc = pyspark.HiveContext(sc)
hc.sql(
    """
    INSERT INTO largeAccumulatorTable
    PARTITION (batch_id = {0})
    SELECT * FROM stagingBatchId{0}
    """
    .format(batch_id)
)
```

I execute it using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
spark-submit \
    --master local[*] \
    --num-executors 8 \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    --executor-memory 2G \
    spark_insert.py
```

I have noticed that the resulting Parquet files in the large accumulating table are very small (some just a few KB) and numerous. I want to avoid this. I want the Parquet files to be large and few. I've tried setting different Hive configuration values at runtime in Pyspark to no avail:

- Set `hive.input.format = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat`
- Set `mapred.map.tasks` to a small number
- Set `num-executors` to a small number
- Use `local[1]` master instead of `local[*]`
- Set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` and `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` to high values

None of these changes had any effect on the number or sizes of Parquet files. However, when I open Cloudera Hue and enter this simple statement:

```
INSERT INTO largeAccumulatorTable
PARTITION (batch_id = XXX)
SELECT * FROM stagingBatchIdXXX
```

It works exactly as I would hope, producing a small number of Parquet files that are all about 100 MB.

What am I doing wrong in Pyspark? How can I make it achieve the same result as in Hue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

spark default shuffle partitions are 200. Based on data size try reducing or increasing the configuration value. `sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=20");`

Comment: I tried this by adding the line `hc.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=20")` and didn't observe any change in the number of Parquet files created. :(